# Generating strings efficiently in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming and would highly appreciate any advice on how this type of program could be written so that it executes faster. Goal is to generate random string until a specific string is found, as in this example 'cat', however, the point is not to find the string 'cat' as fast as possible. From my initial version I have made some improvements and it now runs around 9x faster then in the beginning. 
Some of the things that I found out are that using a list works faster than using:

```
random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

And keeping only necessary amount of characters is faster than if continuously adding NewLetter variable to RandomLetters.
How can this code be improved or rewritten? Also the last line of code I use to determine how many letters per second have been checked. I think it is a better measurement of how fast the program is running instead of time since in some cases 'cat' will be found faster and in some require more attempts. What would be a more accurate way of determining how fast is program? I use the while loop to find 50 cats, otherwise I find the results vary quite a lot when dividing LettersGenerated by time. Here is my code:

```
import random
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
Alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
LettersGenerated = 0
NamesFound = 1
Name = 'cat'
RandomLetters = ''
while NamesFound <= 50:
    while Name not in RandomLetters:
        NewLetter = random.choice(Alphabet)
        RandomLetters = RandomLetters + NewLetter
        LettersGenerated += 1
        lenght = len(RandomLetters)
        if lenght == len(Name)+1:
            RandomLetters = RandomLetters[1:]
            while Name not in RandomLetters:
                NewLetter = random.choice(Alphabet)
                RandomLetters = RandomLetters + NewLetter
                LettersGenerated += 1
                RandomLetters = RandomLetters[1:]
    NamesFound += 1
    RandomLetters = ''
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print(stop-start)
print(LettersGenerated/(stop-start))
```

Comment: There’s a 0.005689576695493855% chance to stumble upon a “cat” in a lot of random three-letter combinations of characters from `string.ascii_lowercase`. Are you sure this is what you want? Generating permutations with `itertools` may be better.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to do.  Are you generating random 3 letter words until you've generated the word "cat" a cettain number of times?

Comment: Although that's a small chance, there are only like 17k 3 letter combinations, so a computer could generate `cat` many times quite easily.  At even a modest 10k permutations per second, you are looking at over 35 appearances of cat per minute.  Still have no idea what the code does however :P

Comment: If you just want to time how long to takes to find 50 cats this code is much shorter https://repl.it/repls/FearlessUnlinedMemory

Comment: Yes, I want to generate a random string until word 'cat' appears in it. If I would try to find a word with lets say 7 characters, it would take all day until it would appear for the first time. So the question is what would be the fastest way to generate a random string where a given word('cat' in this example) appears?